# is it possible to give space between bars using Google ColumnChart

Tags: google-visualization

I am using the Following show the Column Chart for my records, i want to give spaces between  the bars that are generating, please help.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Date', '11-02-2013', '11-02-2013','11-02-2013','11-02-2013'],

          ['Weeks',  10,20,30,5],


        ]);

            var options = {
              title: 'Weekly Average Weight Loss Performance Chart For All Users',
              is3D: true,
              //isStacked: true,
               isHtml: false,
              // colors: ['d2ac2c', 'ff0000', '029748'],
               bar: { groupWidth: '10%' },
               legend:{position: 'bottom'},
               //chbh:'0,10,0',
              //hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
            };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

var options = {
  bar: { groupWidth: '100%' },

Comment: Answers on SO should be more complete than this. While this may answer the question, a bit more context would be helpful.

Comment: This dosen't increase space between two bars, that are grouped together. It only adjusts the width of bars

Answer (score 1):

The usual format for a column chart is that each series has its own column, grouped by rows. Since you have all 4 data points in the same row, you will end up having them all clumped together in the same group. If you change your data, you will get separation as each will be in a separate group:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Date', 'Data'],
  ['11-02-2013', 10],
  ['11-02-2013', 20],
  ['11-02-2013', 30],
  ['11-02-2013', 5]
]);
```

If you want to show multiple people, grouped by weeks, then you would do something like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Date', 'Alan', 'Beatrice', 'Charlie', 'Diana'],
  ['11-02-2013', 10, 5, 15, 20],
  ['11-02-2013', 20, 1, 2, 3],
  ['11-02-2013', 30, 25, 20, 15],
  ['11-02-2013', 5, 7, 9, 11]
]);
```

This will group your data by week (so all 4 people would be shown in the same week as a single group) with gaps between the weeks (between each 'group' of data).